# Who wins in this situation?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, online, strategy, learning

Who wins in this situation, and why? Please explain. Nothing on this site answers my question!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top hand (babr86) wins, as the best poker hand that 9♣ 5♥ can make with the board is

A♣ 9♣ 7♣ 5♣ 3♣

Whereas the K♠ 7♠ hand is playing the board:

A♣ 7♣ 5♣ 3♣ 2♣

Giving the top hand a better kicker in the second card.

Also note that the second player's 7♠ which forms a pair with the board does not factor into their final hand, as a flush is better than a pair.